# How to get access for C drive application folder?

Tags: c#, windows

Following is the code of store attachment of email temporary. This code is working fine with my application. When I crease EXE file. I get this error:

> "Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Application Name\Temp' is
>   denied"

```
if (!Directory.Exists(String.Format("{0}\\Temp", Application.StartupPath)))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Format("{0}\\Temp", Application.StartupPath));
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(String.Format(@"{0}\Temp\{1}", Application.StartupPath, Atchment.Filename));
if (!f.Exists)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(String.Format(@"{0}\Temp\{1}", Application.StartupPath, Atchment.Filename), FileMode.Create))
    {
        int fileLength = (int)Atchment.FileSize;
        byte[] rawdata = (byte[])Atchment.File;
        int byteCount = rawdata.Length;
        fs.Write(rawdata, 0, byteCount);
    }
}
```

I have tried with permission also by `DirectorySecurity folderSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);` but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot write to `c:\program files` without running as admin. Instead, you should write to the user's temp folder.

Comment: How can can I write? Can you suggest me link or example? @crashmstr

Comment: The whole point is that you *don't* write there. If you really must: Run the application as admin (UAC elevation) or modify the permissions of the folder on install. But generally, don't.

Comment: `Path.GetTempPath()` is the place for temporary data

Comment: But when this application go to client, they all need to set permission manually. I think that is not feasible. :(

Comment: The path returned by `GetTempPath()` should be accessible to the user without the need to do anything with permissions.

Comment: Can you please suggest me where should I set this in my code? @AlexK.

Comment: Pass `Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Atchment.Filename)` to the stream constructor

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working properly now. @AlexK.